# How do I resolve the CMake error "Could not find MPI"

Tags: cmake, mpi, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to run a CMakeLists.txt file on a (48h) fresh ubuntu 20.04.3 install. I keep getting the following error when running `cmake .`

```
-- Could NOT find MPI_CXX (missing: MPI_CXX_WORKS)
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find MPI (missing: MPI_CXX_FOUND) (found version "3.1")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:1688 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

As far as I can tell the relevant lines in CMakeLists.txt are the following:

```
# check MPI package...
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER mpicxx)
include_directories(${MPI_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

I have tried to resolve this by installing through apt `mpich`. Although the install works and running `mpich --version` returns (below) the error persists.

```
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

`cmake --version` returns `3.16.3`

I have made restart(s) since installing each package. I have also added to my ~/.bashrc

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/mpicc
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/bin/mpicc
```

which also seems to have done nothing (this after a restart again).

If relevant, I have also installed through apt `cmake, libboost-all-dev, cuda-10-1, libcudnn7, libblas-dev, liblapack-dev, mpi`

I would appreciate any help in the matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) variable to set search path. Best practice is set that variable in command line interface:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=path_to_mpi_lib
```

Anyway you can set the following variables for locating MPI before find_package command (description from FindMPI.cmake):

```
``MPIEXEC_EXECUTABLE``
  Manually specify the location of ``mpiexec``.
``MPI_HOME``
  Specify the base directory of the MPI installation.
``ENV{MPI_HOME}``
  Environment variable to specify the base directory of the MPI installation.
``ENV{I_MPI_ROOT}``
  Environment variable to specify the base directory of the MPI installation.
```

Comment: Running the above (with specifically ` cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/bin/mpicc` returns still the same error.

Is mpicc not the path that it is looking for?

Comment: Isn't the `prefix_path` where cmake find the configuration files of other programs that used cmake? MPI is not built that way (for many of the implementations) so that option might be meaningless.

Comment: CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is the path to search, it's not compiler. For instance: -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/openmpi-version

Comment: Running it with `cmake . -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/bin/mpiexec` indeed resolved this. Thank you.
I am curious as to why it needed this in the first place. Did I muck up the install of mpi for it to not get picked up automatically?

Comment: This helped me. I had a similar problem with mpich library. I installed `Intel oneAPI` that has `mpich` but the cmake could not find. I used `printenv | grep intel` to find the path and after  `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=` used the entire path.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` did not solve my problem. I got it solved by using the variable `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE` mentioned in this issue: https://github.com/3dem/relion/issues/702

As such, my cmake command now looks like:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/home/user/opt/openmpi/bin/mpicc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/home/user/opt/openmpi/bin/mpicxx .
```

, where `/home/user/opt/openmpi/bin` is the location of your MPI binaries.

Comment: You can use variables that I've added. For example, ``MPIEXEC_EXECUTABLE``
  Manually specify the location of ``mpiexec``.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worked for me: Clear the CMake caches.